# Trying to authenticate a user, and process seems stuck

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, express

I'm following along in the [MEAN machine book](https://leanpub.com/mean-machine) and in chapter 9 about Node authentication. I have routes for all users, get, post, put and delete working.

Setup the authenticate route below:

```
// route to authenticate a user (POST http://localhost:8615/api/authenticate)
apiRouter.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

  // find the user
  // select the name, username and password explicitly
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }).select('name username password').exec(function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) throw err;

    // no user with that username was found
    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User no found.'});
    } else {
      // if user is found and password is right
      // create a token
      var token = jwt.sign({
        name: user.name,
        username: user.username
      }, superSecret, {
        expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
      });
    }

  });

});
```

My full server.js file here:
https://github.com/leongaban/awesome-test/blob/865714ade6b2f15ffcd8f1fc72ad0ad18836604b/server.js

I created a new user chris / supersecret

Then tried to authenticate him using Postman and it always hangs up :(

[image]

[image]

Any idea what could be causing it to get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending a response when the user is found and the password matches. You create the token but don't do anything (with it) afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah lol I was missing `res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'Enjoy your token!', token: token
   });`